# How to view depth data of Kinect on RVIZ?

Tags: kinect, vmware, ros, openni, odroid

I connected Kinect for Xbox 360 on Ubuntu on my virtual machine, launched openni.launch and then opened rviz. On Rviz I added pointcloud2 and topic to camera/depth/points. I also changed fixed frame to camera_link. But still I am not able to get anything on Rviz. On the other hand, if I connect Kinect to Odroid-XU4, launch openni.launch on Odroid and run Rviz on my virtual machine by receiving data from Odroid through network connection, I can easily get the depth points on Rviz display. Can someone tell me what could be the problem in my virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the virtual machine have problem with USB, usually USB are not recognized. Is that your case?

Comment: Should not it display "No devices connected" if there was problem with USB connection of Kinect. When I launch openni.launch everything seems to work fine because I can get the list of all the topics if I do "rostopic list". But when I run "rostopic echo" for any topic message published, I get blank terminal.

Comment: Ubuntu version? If it's indigo, you can download libfreenect and try if this will work for you:
    `sudo apt-get install libfreenect-dev`
    `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-launch` and then launch with `roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch`

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu Indigo. I tried with freenect too but still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem with virtual machine is that it is just an emulator which has virtual com ports, hence it doesn't matter how hard you try but you will never be actually getting a RGB-D image on ROS.